# What is better way Making <header> place under the fixed <nav>?

Tags: html, css

In my way, I make `<div class="nav_jumper">` for place `<header>` under the `<nav>`.

```
<nav>......</nav>
<div class="nav_jumper"></div>
<header>......</header>
```

like this...
but I think, It may cause problem in other devices or browser.
How could I make this more better way?

Comment: I do not see any problems that could arise from your sample code, can you please elaborate on the problems you fear may come up on other devices or browsers?

Comment: just for check. I am novice, and I want to know the better ideas even though it is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put some margin on your header with css:

```
header {
  margin-top:70px;
}
```

I used 70 px but you can replace it with your nav height